# How to map nested form values to an HashMap in SpringMVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Budding Java/Spring developer coming from Python/Ruby background trying to understand how things are done on the other side of the fence. :)

I've made an HTML page which looks like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="todos[1][checked]" checked>
<input type="text" name="todos[1][description]" value="Walk cat"><br>
<input type="checkbox" name="todos[2][checked]">
<input type="text" name="todos[2][description]" value="Feed houseplant">
```

When it enters into my controller method I would like it to be a hash that looks something like this (represented in JSON format):

```
{
  "todos": {
    "1": {
        "description": "Walk cat",
        "checked": "on"
    }, 
    "2": {
        "description": "Feed houseplant"
    }
}
```

What I imagined would be it is the following:

```
@RequestMapping(path = "/updateMany", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String todoUpdateMultiple(@RequestParam HashMap<String, String> todos) {  // Also tried with HashMap<String, HashMap<String, String>> but no major difference in behavior
   // … implementation details …
}
```

But with that I get is formatted like:

```
{
   "todos[1][description]": "Walk cat",
   "todos[1][checked]": "on",
   "todos[2][description]": "Feed houseplant"
}
```

We ended up finding a solution where we created a new class `TodoMultiUpdateViewModel` that stores `ArrayList<Todo>` items which in our method ended up being:

```
@RequestMapping(path = "/updateMany", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String todoUpdateMultiple(@ModelAttribute TodoMultiUpdateViewModel todos) {
   // … implementation details …
}
```

While this works, and works well, it seems ridiculous to have to create an extra class just to handle this simple one-off form interaction.